# new vhost - main host AWstats

Tags: awstats

I just began working at this new job and I have to config a new host for stats with awstats. I once used awstats on my own server, no biggie.

Now, I'm on a multi-sites server with the acces_log files nicely splitted. I copied a awstats.conf file from one of the sites that already has (working) stats. I changed the LogFile and SiteDomain values as mentioned from http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_setup.html#BUILD_UPDATE, saved the conf and ran the commands

perl awstats.pl -config=mysite -update
and
perl awstats.pl -config=mysite -output -staticlinks > awstats.mysite.html

(yes I changed it with my infos...)

PROBLEM IS : whenever I try to access the html file or the dynamic page (with the config option on awstats.pl like my working site does), I get the stats of the MAIN site from access.log itself (and not access_log-mysite) from what it says at the top of the page and from the hostname on the left tab (stats for mysite.com)...

what did I do wrong? There's no errors from what I see...

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 1):

Update for config "/etc/awstats/awstats.conf" 
With data in log file "/var/log/httpd/access_log"... 
Phase 1 : First bypass old records, searching new record... 
Direct access after last parsed record (after line 966) 
Jumped lines in file: 966 
Found 966 already parsed records. 
Parsed lines in file: 225 
Found 0 dropped records, 
Found 0 corrupted records, 
Found 0 old records, 
Found 225 new qualified records.

/facepalm WHY DIDN'T i SEE THAT BEFORE...:/

renamed my awstats.www.mysite.ca with a .conf at the end...

WHY?  Because the conf parameter is whats between "awstats." and ".conf" in the filename...  and mine didn't have the .conf!